# iTextsharp underline between strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am using iTextsharp tp create PDF. I have following lines of code to show text on PDF.

```
var contentByte = pdfWriter.DirectContent;
contentByte.BeginText();
contentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 10);
var multiLine = " Request for grant of leave for ____2______days";
contentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, multiLine, 100, 540, 0);
contentByte.EndText();
```

I need to replace "____" with underline. On underline "2" should display.

Please help me to solve this.

I solved this by your answer. thank u.. @ Chris Haas

```
var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontFile, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
var mainFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFont, 10);

//Our Phrase will hold all of our chunks
var p = new Phrase();

//Add the start text
p.Add(new Chunk("Request for grant of leave for ", mainFont));
var space1 = new Chunk("             ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12.0f, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD | iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE));
                     p.Add(space1);
//Add our underlined text
var c = new Chunk("2", mainFont);
c.SetUnderline(0.1f, -1f);
p.Add(c);
var space1 = new Chunk("             ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12.0f, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD | iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE));
                     p.Add(space1);
//Add our end text
p.Add(new Chunk(" days", mainFont));

//Draw our formatted text
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(pdfWriter.DirectContent, PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, p, 100, 540, 0);
```

Comment: Please anyone knows this ???

Comment: you can put html output for creating pdf in itextsharp. So in html you can put <u> </u> tags to accomplish that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `PdfContentByte` directly which only allows you to draw strings you can use a `ColumnText` which allows you access to iText's abstractions, specifically a `Chunk` which has a `SetUnderline()` method on it.

```
//Create our base font and actual font
var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontFile, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
var mainFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFont, 10);

//Our Phrase will hold all of our chunks
var p = new Phrase();

//Add the start text
p.Add(new Chunk("Request for grant of leave for ", mainFont));

//Add our underlined text
var c = new Chunk("2", mainFont);
c.SetUnderline(0.1f, -1f);
p.Add(c);

//Add our end text
p.Add(new Chunk(" days", mainFont));

//Draw our formatted text
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(pdfWriter.DirectContent, PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, p, 100, 540, 0);
```

Comment: used var space1 = new Chunk("             ", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12.0f, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD | iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE));
                     p.Add(space1);  for extending underline.